# Provide hyphens between numbers as a formatting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a requirement to format a 9 digit number by providing hyphens in the appropriate places.If the number is 123456789 ,after formatting it has to be 123-45-6789.To achieve this,I have set the maxlength as 9 in HTML

```
  <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">SSN:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the SSN" id="SSN" name="SSN" data-bind="value: SSN" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(event);" maxlength="9">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-4 labelfont errorMsg" id="Err_SSN">Enter the SSN</label>
        </div>
```

and in the JS,Ihave the following code

```
var Provider = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.ProviderID = ko.observable("");
    self.SSN = ko.observable("");          
};
var blurred = false; //Prevent reformatting when Tab back in.
$("#SSN").blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {
        $("#Err_SSN").text("Enter the SSN");
        $("#Err_SSN").show();
        $(this).addClass('borderclass');
    }
    else {
        if (!blurred) {
            $("#Err_SSN").hide();
            var SSN = $("#SSN").val();
            $("#SSN").val(SSN.substring(0, 3) + "-" + SSN.substring(3, 5) + "-" + SSN.substring(5));
            $("#SSN").removeClass('borderclass');
            Provider.SSN($("#SSN").val());
            blurred = true;
        }
    }
});

  $(document).ready(function () {
   ko.applyBindings(new Provider());
   });
```

The above code works when I tab out after entering 9 digits in the relevant field,but as you may have already figured out,it does not work if I tab back in to edit the data.Now,I know the edit is not happening because the max length is 9 and hyphen is seen as one of the characters.But if I allow more than 9 digits in the field,the number could be considered as invalid.So,if you folks have a better way of achieving my requirement,please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the hyphen(s) when focusing back on the text field:

```
$("#SSN").focus(function(){
    $(this).val() = $(this).val().replace(/-/g,"");
});
```

Not tested, but that's the idea.

Comment: I had to make a few changes to my code and it worked.Thanks a lot for guiding me in the right direction.

Comment: Is there a way to do this and still  keep the hyphens on focusin.I am guessing NO but I would like an answer,if you please.

Comment: possibly using the jQuery Mask Plugin:  http://plugins.jquery.com/mask/  I've used this before but it's been a while.  Should do the trick though!